# Configure SELinux to allow all outbound tcp and udp ports

Tags: centos, centos7, selinux

I have an application that potentially connects to any outbound, remote tcp/udp port. As a result, I want a way to allow all outbound tcp and udp connections.

I understand that you can use a combination of audit2allow and semodule -i for the name_connect denies in the selinx audit log. So far, that is my current workaround. However, it's not scalable for me run this for each port I encounter in the future. I would like to future proof it. I do not know this list of ports to be access ahead of the application's installation.

I hope that there is a configuration to open access to all. Can this configuration extend to allow all outbound tcp, udp ports for all applications (above I only requested for a fixed application)?

Worst case, I will enumerate all possible ports in .pp and .te files and install them with semodule -i once.

**Example**

In this case, my application wanted to connect to 8181. However, I want it to be able to connect to 0

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1543521403.978:2324): avc:  denied  { name_connect } for  pid=26497 comm="java" dest=8181 scontext=system_u:system_r:tomcat_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:intermapper_port_t:s0
```

tclass=tcp_socket

audit2allow generated:

```
module joseph-module 1.0;

require {
    type tomcat_t;
    type intermapper_port_t;
    class tcp_socket name_connect;
}

#============= tomcat_t ==============
allow tomcat_t intermapper_port_t:tcp_socket name_connect;
```

Comment: What domain is your app running under?

Comment: I added an example. from audit2allow. I don't know what part is the domain. tomcat_t? java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsing through the existing SELinux policies, I see that there is a boolean that allows Apache to make outgoing connections to any TCP port. It looks like this:

```
[root@localhost ~]# sesearch -s httpd_t -A -p name_connect -b httpd_can_network_connect
allow httpd_t port_type:tcp_socket name_connect; [ httpd_can_network_connect ]:True
```

I am sure you could adapt this, something like:

```
allow tomcat_t port_type:tcp_socket name_connect;
```

Comment: I will test this out and follow up on the result.

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I have summarized the steps I took in an answer because it does not fit in the comments. However, I have selected your answer because it is the core of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

1) Create a file allow-all-outbound-ports.te

```
module allow-all-outbound-ports 1.0;

require {
    type tomcat_t;
    type port_type;
    class tcp_socket name_connect;
    class udp_socket name_connect;
}

#============= tomcat_t ==============
allow tomcat_t port_type:tcp_socket name_connect;
allow tomcat_t port_type:udp_socket name_connect;
```

I then followed the instructions from
https://relativkreativ.at/articles/how-to-compile-a-selinux-policy-package
on how to create your own package from a .te file.

2) convert the .te into a .mod

```
checkmodule -M -m -o allow-all-outbound-ports.mod allow-all-outbound-ports.te
stdout: checkmodule:  loading policy configuration from allow-all-outbound-ports.te
stdout: checkmodule:  policy configuration loaded
stdout: checkmodule:  writing binary representation (version 19) to allow-all-outbound-ports.mod
```

3) convert the .mod into a .pp

```
semodule_package -o allow-all-outbound-ports.pp -m allow-all-outbound-ports.mod
<no std out>
```

4) install the package

```
semodule -i allow-all-outbound-ports.pp
```

After all these commands, my application was able to communicate on any port. I tried 5357, a port that I never enabled before. Note that `tomcat_t` could be anything of your choosing.